# Why does my Magic Stats menu say I have 18 shouts unlocked, but my list of shouts shows only 17?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Screenshots:

[General Stats page:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4rR9.jpg)

[image]

[Shouts menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t26PM.jpg):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t26PM.jpg]

The same thing happens with Words of Power, I count 38 total, but "Words of Power Unlocked" is only 37, and "Words of Power Unlocked" is 41. Where are the extras coming from?

This doesn't seem to be particularly uncommon either, searching Google for *"Shouts Unlocked" "Shouts Learned"* shows quite a few people with one more unlocked than learned.

Is this related to learning some of the Words at High Hrothgar instead of through dungeon exploring, or something similar?

Comment: I removed your "PS" statement. That's a completely different question, so you should ask in its own question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The game counts the Werewolf's ability *Howl of Terror* as an unlocked shout (I'm assuming you are a werewolf, or have been). I have just tested this on a save where I have found 5 word walls but have yet to kill a dragon (Of course, meaning I haven't unlocked any of these 5 shouts). As I am a werewolf however, the stats page tells me I have unlocked 1 shout. This is further verified by the stats page telling me that my favourite shout is *Howl of Terror*.

Comment: Wouldn't Unrelenting force show up as unlocked by default?

Comment: It does not, no. I have found the word wall  for unrelenting (as I have with 4 other shouts) but not killed the first dragon and so cannot even use it.

Comment: Aha, thank you very much for the answer, it makes sense now :)

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help!